# Operador "or" do blade laravel não funciona

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Quando eu tento usar o operador "or" no blade ele processa errado e da Undefined variable.
Eu estou chamando assim:

```
  {{ $confirmed or false }}
```

Mas ele esta compilando assim:

```
  <?php echo e($confirmed or false); ?>
```

Comment: qual sua intenção? saber se a variável $confirmed existe? se é true? explica melhor

Comment: se é true, se nao existir, automaticamente quero receber false

Answer (score 1):

O uso correto básico é:

```
{{ $confirmed or 'false' }}
```

No caso você está tentando colocar o `false` como um elemento, não uma `string` ou `variável`.

Comment: Coloquei         @if ($confirmed or 'false')
e mesmo assim deu undefined variable

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

`{{ isset($confirmed) ? 'valor se ok' : 'valor se nao existe'; }}`

ou use da forma abaixo para retornar o valor da própria variável:

`{{ isset($confirmed) ? $confirmed : 'valor se nao existe'; }}`